# Java Generics: nested data structure

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, nested

I'm implementing a Java Generics nested data structure based on a simple bidirectional list.

MyList contains Node that contains Info.

```
public class MyList<E> {
    public Node<E> head;
    public Node<E> tail;

    public MyList() {
        this.head = this.tail = null;
    }

    public add(E Info) {
        this.head = new Node<E>(info); // i'm considering just one element
    }
}

public class Node<E> {
    private Node<E> succ;
    private Node<E> pred;
    private E info;

    public Node(E info) {
        this.succ = this.pred = null;
        this.info = info
    }
}

public class Info<K,V> {
    public K key;
    public V value;

    public Info(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Now I would like to achieve the following.

1. Create an array of MyList objects.
2. each node of each list should contains an Info object;
   3 .the Info object should contains a pair Key (Integer) / Value (MyList object);
3. each node of the list should contains Info objects;
4. each Info object should contains a pair Key (Integer) / Value (String);

First question: I know that Java doesn't allow generic array creation; is there a workaround to create it?

Ok, Let's try with a "flat" object.

```
MyList<Info> myList = new MyList<Info>();
```

Now I create a new Info object that the add method will place inside a Node.

```
myList.add(new Info<Integer,MyList<E>>(new Integer(10), new MyList<Info>()));
```

But trying to go more far...

```
myList.head.value.insert(new Info<Integer,myList<Info>>(new Integer(10), new myList<Info>()));
```

...throws the following error:

```
cannot find symbol,
symbol: method insert(Info<Integer,MyList<Info>>)
location: class Object
```

Second question: what about the class Object? I supposed to have a List object!

Third question: is this the right way to manage Generics?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can not instantiate a generic array, but you can always use an [**`ArrayList`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). You get same functionality in a safe way with negligible overhead.
2. While creating the list, you did not specify type arguments of `Info`

   ```
   MyList<Info> myList = new MyList<Info>();
   ```

   In stead, it should have been

   ```
   MyList<Info> myList = new MyList<Info<Integer, MyList<Info<Integer, String>>>>();
   ```

   Since you did not specify type arguments, Java compiler defaulted them to `Object` class (resulting in above error).
3. The error was a result of improperly handling generics. The above fix should solve the error. In general, avoid raw types (always supply appropriate type arguments).

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: basing my research on your reply, I found the right way to initialize my generics nested objects: `MyList<Info<Integer, MyList<Info<Integer, String>>>> myList = new MyList<Info<Integer, MyList<Info<Integer, String>>>>();` and 
`myList.add(new Info<Integer, MyList<Info<Integer, String>>>(new Integer(10), new MyList<Info<Integer, String>>()));` Finally it seems very confused, maybe I should find an easier way. Thanks for your help!